# How do I exclude specific subfolders within an included folder using Geta Sitemap?

Tags: episerver

How do I exclude subfolders that match a specific pattern from a sitemap that sit inside an included folder?

For example, I wish to exclude all subfolders matching the following criteria: /Research/Content/Short-reports/*pptx/

While still including all other folders within:
/Research/Content/Short-reports/

Geta seems to ignore my wildcard and treats it as literal text.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Geta only does string matching and won't handle any wildcard/regex.

Geta does recommend you implement your own IContentFilter for custom filtering.

If the folders in question are Content Folders in the CMS, one option could be to create a ContentArea property in global settings to hold references to all the folders you wish to exclude. Then, in the ShouldExcludeContent method of your IContentFilter implementation, you can perform a check to see if the content is a descendant of one of the folders you added to the global setting.

```cs
public class MyCustomSitemapContentFilter : Geta.SEO.Sitemaps.Utils.ContentFilter
{
    public override bool ShouldExcludeContent(IContent content)
    {
        var baseEvaluation = base.ShouldExcludeContent(content);

        var shouldExclude = false;

        //shouldExclude = code to check if content is 
        //   is descendant of any of the folders referenced
        //   in global setting property

        return shouldExclude || baseEvaluation;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful and much appreciated. Thank you